# Plotting tick data by using dual x-axis in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, coordinates

there. I'm facing difficulty with respect to plotting daily tick data by setting date and bs(buy&sell) as x-axis and calling for your help.

This is what I want to plot.

[image]

I've tried three different ways and searched for similar questions. Yet, still cannot get the desired result. I would like to plot bs on x-axis, price on y-axis, and label maximum bs to corresponding price, maximum and minimum price while setting date as second x-axis.

Please see below, the codes and pics might elaborate what I want to express.

1.
50% correct, but ggplot sees it as a whole and shares only one set of label(maximum and minimum).

```
ggplot(data=ts,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price)) + 
geom_path()+geom_label(data=ts[which.max(ts$bs),],vjust=1.5,hjust=1.0) +
geom_label(data=ts[which.max(ts$price),],vjust=1,hjust=0) +
geom_label(data=ts[which.min(ts$price),],vjust=-1.5,hjust=0) + 
facet_grid(~date)
```

[image]

2.
Setting date as first x-axis and bs as secondary x-axis.  Not even close.

```
ggplot()+
geom_path(data=ts,aes(x=date,y=price))+
geom_path(data=ts,aes(x=bs,y=price))+facet_grid(~date)
```

[image]

3.
If I separate daily data into each file, combine, and plot, then it become like this. Only two bins in one graph.

```
library(reshapes2)

library(cowplot)


plot629 <-ggplot(data=m629,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+
geom_path()+geom_label(data=m629[which.max(m629$bs),],vjust=1.5,hjust=1.0)+
geom_label(data=m629[which.max(m629$price),],vjust=1,hjust=0)+
geom_label(data=m629[which.min(m629$price),],vjust=-1.5,hjust=0)


plot630 <- ggplot(data=m630,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+geom_path()+
geom_label(data=m630[which.max(m630$bs),],vjust=1.5,hjust=1.0)+
geom_label(data=m630[which.max(m630$price),],vjust=1,hjust=0)+
geom_label(data=m630[which.min(m630$price),],vjust=-1.5,hjust=0)


plot701 <- ggplot(data=m701,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+
geom_path()+geom_label(data=m701[which.max(m701$bs),],vjust=1.5,hjust=1.0)+
geom_label(data=m701[which.max(m701$price),],vjust=1,hjust=0)+
geom_label(data=m701[which.min(m701$price),],vjust=-1.5,hjust=0)

ggdraw() + draw_plot(plot629,0,0,0.3,1) + 
draw_plot(plot630,0.5,0,0.3,1) + draw_plot(plot701,1,0,0.3,1)
```

[image]

As shown above, is it possible to do what I want by using ggplot? Or, is there any package that I can use for? And btw, is it possible to get rid of the number shown below each bin and replace by date?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the simple dataset

```
structure(list(price = c(11315L, 11316L, 11317L, 11318L, 11319L, 
11320L, 11321L, 11322L, 11323L, 11324L, 11325L, 11326L, 11327L, 
11328L, 11329L, 11330L, 11331L, 11332L, 11333L, 11334L, 11335L, 
11336L, 11337L, 11338L, 11339L, 11340L, 11341L, 11342L, 11343L, 
11344L, 11345L, 11346L, 11347L, 11348L, 11349L, 11350L, 11351L, 
11352L, 11353L, 11354L, 11355L, 11356L, 11357L, 11358L, 11359L, 
11360L, 11361L, 11362L, 11363L, 11364L, 11365L, 11366L, 11367L, 
11368L, 11369L, 11370L, 11371L, 11372L, 11373L, 11374L, 11375L, 
11376L, 11377L, 11378L, 11379L, 11380L, 11381L, 11382L, 11383L, 
11384L, 11385L, 11386L, 11387L, 11388L, 11389L, 11390L, 11391L, 
11392L, 11393L, 11394L, 11395L, 11396L, 11397L, 11398L, 11399L, 
11400L, 11401L, 11402L, 11403L, 11404L, 11405L, 11406L, 11407L, 
11408L, 11409L, 11410L, 11411L, 11412L, 11413L, 11414L, 11415L, 
11416L, 11417L, 11418L, 11419L, 11420L, 11421L, 11422L, 11423L, 
11424L, 11425L, 11426L, 11427L, 11428L, 11429L, 11430L, 11431L, 
11432L, 11433L, 11434L, 11435L, 11436L, 11437L, 11438L, 11439L, 
11440L, 11441L, 11442L, 11443L, 11444L, 11445L, 11446L, 11447L, 
11448L, 11449L, 11450L, 11451L, 11452L, 11453L, 11454L, 11455L, 
11456L, 11457L, 11458L, 11459L, 11460L, 11461L, 11462L, 11463L, 
11464L, 11465L, 11466L, 11467L, 11468L, 11469L, 11470L, 11471L, 
11472L, 11473L, 11474L, 11475L, 11476L, 11477L, 11478L, 11479L, 
11480L, 11481L, 11482L, 11483L, 11484L, 11485L, 11486L, 11487L, 
11488L, 11489L, 11490L, 11491L, 11492L, 11493L, 11494L, 11495L, 
11496L, 11497L, 11498L, 11499L, 11500L, 11501L, 11502L, 11503L, 
11504L, 11505L, 11506L, 11507L, 11508L, 11509L, 11510L, 11511L, 
11512L, 11513L, 11514L, 11515L, 11516L, 11517L, 11518L, 11519L, 
11520L, 11521L, 11522L, 11523L, 11524L, 11525L, 11526L, 11527L, 
11528L, 11357L, 11358L, 11359L, 11360L, 11361L, 11362L, 11363L, 
11364L, 11365L, 11366L, 11367L, 11368L, 11369L, 11370L, 11371L, 
11372L, 11373L, 11374L, 11375L, 11376L, 11377L, 11378L, 11379L, 
11380L, 11381L, 11382L, 11383L, 11384L, 11385L, 11386L, 11387L, 
11388L, 11389L, 11390L, 11391L, 11392L, 11393L, 11394L, 11395L, 
11396L, 11397L, 11398L, 11399L, 11400L, 11401L, 11402L, 11403L, 
11404L, 11405L, 11406L, 11407L, 11408L, 11409L, 11410L, 11411L, 
11412L, 11413L, 11414L, 11415L, 11416L, 11417L, 11418L, 11419L, 
11420L, 11421L, 11422L, 11423L, 11424L, 11425L, 11426L, 11427L, 
11428L, 11429L, 11430L, 11431L, 11432L, 11433L, 11434L, 11435L, 
11436L, 11437L, 11438L, 11439L, 11440L, 11441L, 11442L, 11443L, 
11444L, 11445L, 11446L, 11447L, 11448L, 11449L, 11450L, 11451L, 
11452L, 11453L, 11454L, 11455L, 11456L, 11457L, 11458L, 11459L, 
11460L, 11461L, 11462L, 11463L, 11464L, 11465L, 11466L, 11467L, 
11468L, 11469L, 11470L, 11471L, 11472L, 11473L, 11474L, 11475L, 
11476L, 11477L, 11478L, 11479L, 11480L, 11481L, 11482L, 11483L, 
11484L, 11485L, 11486L, 11487L, 11488L, 11489L, 11490L, 11491L, 
11492L, 11493L, 11494L, 11495L, 11496L, 11497L, 11498L, 11499L, 
11500L, 11501L, 11502L, 11415L, 11416L, 11417L, 11418L, 11419L, 
11420L, 11421L, 11422L, 11423L, 11424L, 11425L, 11426L, 11427L, 
11428L, 11429L, 11430L, 11431L, 11432L, 11433L, 11434L, 11435L, 
11436L, 11437L, 11438L, 11439L, 11440L, 11441L, 11442L, 11443L, 
11444L, 11445L, 11446L, 11447L, 11448L, 11449L, 11450L, 11451L, 
11452L, 11453L, 11454L, 11455L, 11456L, 11457L, 11458L, 11459L, 
11460L, 11461L, 11462L, 11463L, 11464L, 11465L, 11466L, 11467L, 
11468L, 11469L, 11470L, 11471L, 11472L, 11473L, 11474L, 11475L, 
11476L, 11477L, 11478L, 11479L, 11480L, 11481L, 11482L, 11483L, 
11484L, 11485L, 11486L, 11487L, 11488L, 11489L, 11490L, 11491L, 
11492L, 11493L, 11494L, 11495L, 11496L, 11497L, 11498L, 11499L, 
11500L, 11501L, 11502L, 11503L, 11504L, 11505L, 11506L, 11507L, 
11508L, 11509L, 11510L, 11511L, 11512L, 11513L, 11514L, 11515L, 
11516L, 11517L, 11518L, 11519L, 11520L, 11521L, 11522L, 11523L, 
11524L, 11525L, 11526L, 11527L, 11528L, 11529L, 11530L, 11531L, 
11532L, 11533L, 11534L, 11535L, 11536L, 11537L, 11538L, 11539L, 
11540L, 11541L, 11542L, 11543L, 11544L, 11545L, 11546L, 11547L, 
11548L, 11549L, 11550L, 11551L, 11552L, 11553L, 11554L, 11555L, 
11556L, 11557L, 11558L, 11559L, 11560L, 11561L, 11562L, 11563L, 
11564L, 11565L, 11566L, 11567L, 11568L, 11569L, 11570L, 11571L, 
11572L, 11573L, 11574L, 11575L, 11576L, 11577L, 11578L, 11579L, 
11580L, 11581L, 11582L, 11583L, 11584L, 11585L, 11586L, 11587L, 
11588L, 11589L, 11590L, 11591L, 11592L, 11593L, 11594L, 11595L, 
11596L, 11597L, 11598L, 11599L, 11600L, 11601L, 11602L, 11603L, 
11604L, 11605L, 11606L, 11607L, 11608L, 11609L, 11610L, 11611L, 
11612L, 11613L, 11614L, 11615L, 11616L, 11617L, 11618L, 11619L, 
11620L, 11621L, 11622L, 11623L), bs = c(236L, 340L, 266L, 306L, 
300L, 546L, 700L, 1106L, 1064L, 1312L, 1358L, 1126L, 876L, 1382L, 
1382L, 2290L, 2292L, 2282L, 2454L, 2710L, 3082L, 2252L, 2214L, 
2574L, 2498L, 3088L, 2644L, 2664L, 2558L, 2452L, 2508L, 2122L, 
2188L, 2152L, 1730L, 2222L, 1210L, 1074L, 1736L, 1750L, 2340L, 
2252L, 2004L, 2448L, 2590L, 4622L, 3428L, 3642L, 3628L, 3960L, 
4020L, 2690L, 2110L, 1974L, 1018L, 1182L, 796L, 788L, 762L, 780L, 
1442L, 1048L, 814L, 862L, 616L, 916L, 808L, 626L, 552L, 506L, 
588L, 888L, 1222L, 1942L, 1300L, 1856L, 1284L, 968L, 932L, 1942L, 
1320L, 1218L, 1514L, 1746L, 1886L, 3186L, 2540L, 2194L, 2314L, 
2166L, 3072L, 2344L, 2238L, 2568L, 2132L, 2806L, 2606L, 2492L, 
2610L, 2860L, 3754L, 2940L, 2754L, 3246L, 2912L, 4018L, 3402L, 
3534L, 3374L, 3028L, 3760L, 3820L, 3822L, 3890L, 3296L, 4596L, 
2780L, 2546L, 2958L, 2706L, 2990L, 2558L, 2518L, 2462L, 2110L, 
2818L, 2276L, 2184L, 1828L, 1436L, 1878L, 1468L, 1464L, 1590L, 
1580L, 2524L, 1586L, 1480L, 1702L, 1568L, 2490L, 2074L, 1872L, 
1872L, 1274L, 2000L, 1252L, 1194L, 1422L, 1422L, 1630L, 1668L, 
1798L, 2264L, 1806L, 2244L, 1480L, 2028L, 1616L, 2074L, 2066L, 
1798L, 1514L, 1440L, 1116L, 1308L, 780L, 816L, 904L, 1162L, 1434L, 
1042L, 1074L, 666L, 400L, 356L, 164L, 130L, 110L, 48L, 48L, 54L, 
36L, 34L, 28L, 106L, 32L, 56L, 64L, 54L, 38L, 24L, 18L, 42L, 
34L, 86L, 42L, 76L, 196L, 316L, 316L, 422L, 418L, 358L, 300L, 
348L, 378L, 238L, 214L, 178L, 248L, 168L, 76L, 18L, 2L, 16L, 
40L, 42L, 32L, 52L, 232L, 404L, 904L, 480L, 554L, 672L, 562L, 
1364L, 1352L, 1574L, 1472L, 1534L, 1732L, 1218L, 1664L, 1862L, 
1984L, 2602L, 1908L, 1396L, 1736L, 1132L, 1070L, 804L, 860L, 
784L, 814L, 950L, 690L, 890L, 1086L, 804L, 880L, 1228L, 946L, 
1384L, 1164L, 1292L, 1430L, 1506L, 1064L, 1038L, 1348L, 764L, 
668L, 924L, 832L, 1178L, 700L, 742L, 714L, 934L, 1078L, 730L, 
974L, 1438L, 1516L, 2202L, 1916L, 1554L, 1138L, 978L, 1896L, 
2430L, 2902L, 3106L, 3072L, 3358L, 1918L, 2390L, 1996L, 1934L, 
2038L, 1172L, 972L, 2044L, 2840L, 5032L, 3938L, 4128L, 4188L, 
4734L, 4882L, 4094L, 4770L, 4206L, 3456L, 5638L, 3584L, 4052L, 
3942L, 3352L, 3846L, 2864L, 2456L, 2492L, 2004L, 3100L, 1312L, 
1266L, 1396L, 1514L, 2328L, 1782L, 1180L, 1454L, 1646L, 2994L, 
1752L, 912L, 712L, 596L, 502L, 322L, 260L, 402L, 666L, 1098L, 
1124L, 1400L, 1846L, 1724L, 1316L, 1868L, 2426L, 2210L, 1480L, 
1552L, 1062L, 956L, 1558L, 1726L, 2188L, 2156L, 764L, 866L, 674L, 
372L, 226L, 112L, 132L, 204L, 260L, 132L, 86L, 384L, 234L, 126L, 
240L, 254L, 348L, 392L, 706L, 740L, 924L, 998L, 752L, 850L, 1106L, 
1654L, 1234L, 978L, 702L, 886L, 946L, 1704L, 1350L, 1666L, 1758L, 
2132L, 2362L, 1842L, 1934L, 1852L, 1788L, 2924L, 2844L, 3342L, 
3320L, 3106L, 2680L, 1804L, 1722L, 1456L, 1510L, 1970L, 1504L, 
1646L, 1076L, 1178L, 1380L, 1502L, 1306L, 874L, 1042L, 1122L, 
472L, 472L, 292L, 260L, 570L, 722L, 538L, 570L, 900L, 1162L, 
774L, 1102L, 322L, 184L, 176L, 104L, 214L, 522L, 778L, 862L, 
814L, 1068L, 790L, 480L, 548L, 282L, 186L, 274L, 206L, 272L, 
192L, 192L, 298L, 478L, 664L, 478L, 516L, 718L, 490L, 606L, 472L, 
484L, 460L, 412L, 640L, 680L, 814L, 1044L, 1122L, 1306L, 418L, 
444L, 822L, 902L, 922L, 330L, 310L, 302L, 150L, 494L, 348L, 342L, 
366L, 364L, 290L, 248L, 416L, 448L, 774L, 936L, 842L, 902L, 1598L, 
2906L, 3566L, 2598L, 2360L, 2500L, 1998L, 3166L, 2764L, 2546L, 
2016L, 2518L, 3038L, 2286L, 2034L, 2612L, 2418L, 2756L, 2186L, 
1912L, 2182L, 2312L, 2118L, 1730L, 1412L, 1504L, 1474L, 3362L, 
3474L, 3086L, 3102L, 3344L, 3926L, 3214L, 3318L, 3646L, 3458L, 
3908L, 2820L, 3734L, 3782L, 2886L, 2428L, 1940L, 2666L, 2658L, 
1680L, 1716L, 950L, 732L, 668L, 970L, 932L, 972L, 1282L, 890L, 
1074L, 1058L, 1322L, 1674L, 1646L, 860L, 1436L, 1160L, 1216L, 
1872L, 1898L, 2200L, 2316L, 2392L, 2432L, 1926L, 1444L, 926L, 
1126L, 1076L, 878L, 1276L, 528L, 426L, 162L), date = c(2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 
2020629, 2020629, 2020629, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 2020630, 
2020630, 2020630, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 2020701, 
2020701)), row.names = c(NA, -569L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can't really have date as a secondary x axis. Suppose you have two data points on two different dates where bs was the same. Where on the x axis would you plot these two points? If you put them both at the correct place for bs then the Date will be wrong. If you plot them on the correct dates the bs will be wrong. What you are suggesting doesn't make a lot of sense. The best you can do is to facet, as in example 1, and get the min / max values for each day on the plot.

Comment: @AllanCameron, could you give hint or further elaborate  how to label min/max values for each days by using facet_grid?  As shown in example 1, the min/max label is for the whole dataset, so the min value appears at 2020629, and max happens at 2020709.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by creating labels into individual dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)

#Data for labels
labs1 <- ts %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(price==min(price))
labs2 <- ts %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(price==max(price))
labs3 <- ts %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(bs==max(bs))
#Plot,
ggplot(ts,aes(x=bs,y=price))+
  geom_path()+
  geom_label(data=labs1,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+
  geom_label(data=labs2,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+
  geom_label(data=labs3,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price))+
  facet_wrap(.~date,scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Duck. It seems that if I put too much dates in one graph, labels would takes too much space and become confusing. I will think if it's necessarily to label each date.

Comment: You can also rotate your facet labels to fit more facets in there without wrapping the text.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information you provided, it sounds like you were close to what you wanted with the facet example, but needed to label all the facets.  A good approach here would be to create a summary data frame from your original dataset which is composed of the min and max values for each facet group (in this case, `ts$date`).  You then pass that summary data frame back to the `geom_label` function and there ya go.

I've included the option to use `geom_label_repel` from the `ggrepel` package, which can avoid the labels wandering outside of your facets.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

# make summary data frame
ts_group <- ts %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  dplyr::filter(bs==max(bs) | bs==min(bs))

# faceted plot
ggplot(data=ts,aes(x=bs,y=price,label=price)) + 
  geom_path()+
  geom_label_repel(
    data=ts_group,
    size=3) +
  facet_grid(~date)
```

[image]

Note that for the first date, two values actually shared the minimum value of `ts$bs`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it to see if I can fix this problem.